# Delay crashes the app

Tags: android

I have this code in MainActivity:

```
  boolean running = true;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int secs = 1;
                while(running){
                    Utils.delay(secs, new Utils.DelayCallback() {
                        int  seconds = 0;
                        TextView licznik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.licznik);
                        @Override
                        public void afterDelay() {
                            seconds = seconds + 1;
                            licznik.setText(Integer.toString(seconds));

                        }
                    });


                }
            }
        }).start();


    }
```

and its Utils class:

```
    import android.os.Handler;

public class Utils {

    // Delay mechanism

    public interface DelayCallback{
        void afterDelay();
    }

    public static void delay(int secs, final DelayCallback delayCallback){
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                delayCallback.afterDelay();
            }
        }, secs * 1000); // afterDelay will be executed after (secs*1000) milliseconds.
    }
}
```

I found this method on StackOverflow, but it crashes my app after I click the button
What's wrong? Please help, if I should do another method for delay, tell me which
error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `Handler` on a background `Thread` that hasn't called `Looper.prepare()`, and also touching a UI component off of the main thread.

Try:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                delayCallback.afterDelay();
            }
        }, secs * 1000);
```

and see if that fixes the problem.  Either way, though, you'll probably run into issues, since the `while(running)` call is going to trigger a lot without a sleep...

Comment: It works, But I dont know why, it set weird numbers to "licznik" TextView. I want it to be a counter

Comment: After the Utils.delay call add a Thread.sleep(secs * 1000); call, since it looks like you're trying to increment based on the delay.  Right now, the while loop is firing tons Runnables before that second has passed.

Comment: It likely won't fully fix your issue, but that's outside of the scope of the originally posted question, since there are other things wrong -- like setting "seconds = 0" and using "secs" as the argument for the delay method.  You might want to just look into the class CountDownTimer.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: please can u tell me, what's the simplest way to make timer in background (another thread) and update TextView every second?

Comment: See my above comment about CountDownTimer, that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but im looking for something that will run if running==true, I'm not looking for counter down

Comment: If you can't accomplish it with a CountDownTimer, you're not really thinking outside of the box :P.  Also, as you've stated, this has already answered the originally posted question.  If you have additional questions open a separate question since this is running long in comments.  Hint:  new CountDownTimer(REALLY_LONG_TIME, 1000)...and use cancel if running is set to false...

Comment: please answer my last question, how to cancel CountDownTimer?

Comment: Both CountDownTimer.start() and CountDownTimer.cancel() are methods defined on the class.  Give the documentation a peek, I provided it in one of the comments above.

Comment: np, happy coding